# How can I select the same item in a streaming JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java Swing application in which a JTable which is updated(new items are added at the top) when new events occur. 
My problem is, the selected item is not remained as selected when a new item is added. For example, the 3rd item is selected at first, then one item is added to the table. It still selects the 3rd item, but I want it to select the 4th item(the original one).
How can I do it?

Comment: add ListSelectionListener, to debug whats output is generated, set selection (toggle) to desired index from JTables view, no idea whats happens in your case if is there more that one row selected

Comment: Updates to the table should be done by updating the TableModel. Then the row selection will remain. If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.